# Laravel - how to add routes if public server url includes path

Tags: php, apache, laravel, lumen

I have a problem defining routes for my application, if the application is accessibly via a server url that contains a path.

I want `/`to be the Application (Laravel project), while `/_api` is a Lumen project, defining a RESTful API

I have an Apache server configuration as follows:

```
<VirtualHost local.dev:80>
    ... # config for local.dev/

    Alias /_api ".../api/public"
    <Directory ".../api/public">
    ...
    </Directory
</VirtualHost>
```

`local.dev/_api` is a lumen project.

`$app->get('/_api'...` - this works, if I request `local.dev/_api`

`$app->get('/_api/messages'...` - I get an Exception if I request `local.dev/_api/messages`: `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php`

Answer (score 1):

In the `.htaccess` file of my project at `/_api` I hade to change this line:

`RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ /_api/index.php [L]`